# Why does my Android 2.2 powered Samsung Galaxy I5510 receive duplicated messages (SMS)?

Tags: sms, samsung-galaxy-551

I own a brand new Samsung Galaxy I5510 (Android 2.2). Everything works fine and I really like the device.

### My problem is:

<strike>Every time</strike> *Some times* I receive a message from a phone number that is not in my contact list, the phone continues receiving it every few hours.

### Facts I pointed out:

- The time between those messages is not constant.
- It never happened when the number was in my contact list.
- Deleting the thread does not solve the problem.
- The senders do not fool me and send the message again and again.
- It seems to stop after a day or two.
- restart of the phone does not solve the problem.
- I am not sure if it really receives the message again or if it just copies the old one.

Does anybody has an idea what could cause the described behavior?

*Thank you!*

**EDIT:** Another point why it is not likely to be a provider issue: I never received a duplicated message while the phone was turned off. Means: I never switched the phone on in the morning and received one or more such messages instantly.

**EDIT 2:** I looked through all the phone log. It happened by now for two numbers. Both were not in my contact list. The occurencies and their time of day are:

#### +491773**4537

```
15:38
17:23
19:19
21:41
00:37
phone off
13:20
16:12
20:48
phone off
09:59
10:16
14:10
phone off
12:46
21:04
--------
13 times
```

#### +491635**4554

```
23:39
phone off
12:20
13:09
14:44
16:16
17:51
19:28
21:02
23:39
phone off
07:28
08:16
09:32
10:51
12:17
15:28
17:00
18:27
20:04
21:21
22:47
--------
20 times
```

### Message from numbers that did not repeat:

```
+491762**21169
+491797**1598
+436508**7821
+336782**105
```

Comment: What's your carrier?  I experience "duplicate" messages all the time on Verizon.  I believe it's a carrier issue.

Comment: @Al Everett: Why did you remove the android tags?

Comment: @Bryan Denny: My carrier is www.o2.de (Telefonica). But I don't think that its their issue: I didn't change my simcard and had no problems on my old phone. Maybe the I5510 does not confirm the receivement of a sms which sender isn't in the contact list...

Comment: @Simon Android tags are considered redundant here (because you're already on a site about Android, there is no need to tag it unless you're tagging a specific version of it, 2.2-froyo, etc.)

Comment: @Bryan Denny: Ok, I thought tagging it 2.2-froyo might be right as I thought it could be a issue to the OS (at that specific version). Why do general `android` tags exist?

Comment: How many times does it repeat? Does it always stop after a certain number or does it last until you shut the phone off?

Comment: @Kyle — First 13 times, secound 20 times. Shutting down and restarting does not help! Please see my edit! Thanks!

Comment: i hope that samsung comes with a sollution fast, because i5510 has a lot of software problems

Comment: @Simon: Android tags exist primarily because when questions are migrated from other sites they are (correctly) tagged "android" there, and the tags are maintained in the migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem simply disappeared after a few weeks. I guess the carrier changed something or my phone got updated without informing me... Who knows.

Comment: Those are the worst. Glad you got it sorted.